# Python: map NLTK Stanford POS tags to WordNet POS tags

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, part-of-speech

I'm reading a list of sentences and tagging each word with NLTK's Stanford POS tagger.  I get outputs like so:

```
wordnet_sense = []

for o in output:
    a = st.tag(o)
    wordnet_sense.append(a)
```

outputs: `[[(u'feel', u'VB'), (u'great', u'JJ')], [(u'good', u'JJ')]]`

I want to map these words with their POS, so that they are recognised in WordNet.

I've attempted this:

```
sense = []

for i in wordnet_sense:
    tmp = []

    for tok, pos in i:
        lower_pos = pos[0].lower()

        if lower_pos in ['a', 'n', 'v', 'r', 's']:
            res = wn.synsets(tok, lower_pos)
            if len(res) > 0:
                a = res[0]
        else:
            a = "[{0}, {1}]".format(tok, pos)

        tmp.append(a)

    sense.append(tmp)

print sense
```

outputs: `[Synset('feel.v.01'), '[great, JJ]'], ['[good, JJ]']]`

So `feel` is recognised as a verb, but `great` and `good` are not recognised as adjectives.  I've also checked if `great` and `good` actually belong in Wordnet because I thought they weren't being mapped if they weren't there, but they are.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a cute function from [`pywsd`](https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L92):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def penn2morphy(penntag, returnNone=False):
    morphy_tag = {'NN':wn.NOUN, 'JJ':wn.ADJ,
                  'VB':wn.VERB, 'RB':wn.ADV}
    try:
        return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
    except:
        return None if returnNone else ''
```

Comment: See also: https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

Answer (score 2):

```
def wordnet_pos_code(tag):
    if tag.startswith('NN'):
        return wn.NOUN
    elif tag.startswith('VB'):
        return wn.VERB
    elif tag.startswith('JJ'):
        return wn.ADJ
    elif tag.startswith('RB'):
        return wn.ADV
    else:
        return ''



print wordnet_pos_code('NN')`
```

As well as the answer provided, I've found this that also works.