# How to convert NLTK tags to wordnet tags

Tags: python

I am struggling with converting NLTK tags to wordnet tags. I have a series object entitled "tokens", and inside "tokens" are series of various lengths containing the tokenized and NLTK-tagged contents of tweets. For instance:

```
[('sitting', 'VBG'), ('democrat', 'NN'), ('senator', 'NN'), ('trial', 'NN'), ('corruption', 'NN'), ('barely', 'RB'), ('heard', 'JJ'), ('peep', 'NN'), ('mainstream', 'NN'), ('media', 'NNS')]
```

Below is my code I'm trying to use to replace the NLTK tags with wordnet tags, but I am getting the error:

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
tokens = tokens['tokens'].apply(lambda v: nltk.pos_tag(v))

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

for tokenlist in tokens:
    for token in tokenlist:
        for (word, tag) in token:
            if tag.startswith('J'):
                tag = 'a'
            elif tag.startswith('V'):
                tag = 'v'
            elif tag.startswith('R'):
                tag = 'r'
            elif tag.startswith('N'):
                tag = 'n'
            else:
                tag = 'n'
            lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos=tag)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-122-0502b4ebc79b>", line 4, in <module>
    for (word, tag) in token:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Am I incorrect for thinking I can simply set the value of "tag" to the wordnet tag letters if my "if/elif/else" conditions are met?

Comment: Where did you find this question asked before?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586721/wordnet-lemmatization-and-pos-tagging-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458896/python-map-nltk-stanford-pos-tags-to-wordnet-pos-tags

Comment: When you replace `for (word, tag) in token` by `for x in token` and add the line `print(x)` below, what do you get as output?

Comment: I get all of the word/tag combos printed! Which strikes me as meaning the amount of "for"s in my loop is correct?

Comment: Can you please show what exactly you get (show, don't describe)?

Comment: And please also show the full traceback of the original error ([edit] the question).

Comment: Sure thing; to your first comment, here's what I get: ```

lot
NN
info
NNS
reading
VBG
dj
NN
said
VBD
caribbean
JJ
people
NNS
building
VBG
starting
VBG
playing
VBG
drake
NN
colin
NN
kaepernick
NN
donates
VBZ
black
JJ
youth
NN
project
NN
la
NNS
county
VBP
sheriff
JJ
deputies
NNS
murder
VBP
suspect
NN
police
NNS
depts
NNS
killed
VBN
black
JJ
people
NNS
year
NN
call
NN
justice
NN
mall
NN
tries
NNS
block
VBP
blm
NN
protest
NN
teen
JJ
died
VBD
shielding
VBG
girls
NNS
gunfire

``` This goes on until it hits the end

Comment: And when you replace `print(x)` by `print(repr(x))`?

Comment: 'brutality'
'NN'
'cases'
'NNS'
'growing'
'VBG'
'photo'
'NN'
'sideniggaparalegal'
'JJ'
'urbansaseko'
'JJ'
'mysquad'
'NN'
'woman'
'NN'
'wants'
'VBZ'
'million'
'CD'
'new'
'JJ'

same as before, however, the words and tags are separated with quotes

Comment: So `x` are individual strings, not pairs of strings. That's why you can't unpack them to `(word, tag)`. That's why you got that error message.

Comment: What part of your code exactly does the first example (after "for instance") correspond to? It would help if you made your code into a [mre].